# XAML ignores changed Binding value

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, mvvm-light

I found millions of Answers for my questions but nothing worked, maybe i don´t see the easy solution.

In my MVVM-(Light) Application i want to Bind the Visibility Property to the ViewModel:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding AddMenuVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
...
</StackPanel>
```

My ViewModel starts with:

```
public class OrderMainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public OrderMainViewModel()
    {
        if (CurrentUser.Default.UserLevel < 5)
        {
            AddMenuVisibility = false;

        }
        else
        {
            AddMenuVisibility = true;
        }
}
```

Property:

```
        public const string AddMenuVisibilityPropertyName = "AddMenuVisibility";

    private bool _addMenuVisibility = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the AddMenuVisibility property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public bool AddMenuVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return _addMenuVisibility;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_addMenuVisibility == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _addMenuVisibility = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(AddMenuVisibilityPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

The Default Value of CurrenUser.Default.UserLevel is 1 so it reaches the false Value first. Later it reaches the true Value, but the "real" Visibility Status in XAML isn´t changed.
If i change the first declaration to true, it stays visible.

Comment: "_I found millions of Answers for my questions but nothing worked_". What then are the chances that a further answer here will help you, realistically? Im mean if 1000000 answers didn't help, the 1000001st answer will very likely not help either...

Comment: Aside from responding to a quite silly remark with an equally and deservingly silly comment, from the top of my head i can think of four problem scenarios that might give you the observed troublesome behavior: (1) You seem to do the test against `CurrentUser.Default.UserLevel` only in the constructor of the viewmodel. That means, the test is only happen when viewmodel is constructed, and then never again. You would obviously need to test against `CurrentUser.Default.UserLevel` whenever `CurrentUser.Default.UserLevel` changes, not just the moment your viewmodel is created.

Comment: Scenario (2): If you managed to change your code so that `CurrentUser.Default.UserLevel` is tested (and AddMenuVisibility changed) _whenever_ it changes, make sure you only operate on **one** _OrderMainViewModel_ instance (the one that is used for the databinding). Scenario (3): Maybe the binding cannot resolve the source of the binding (the OrderMainViewModel instance). Since the binding uses the DataContext as binding source, make sure that the DataContext for that StackPanel is actually referring to the OrderMainViewModel instance.

Comment: And the last scenario i can think of (4): Perhaps the implementation of your BooleanToVisibilityConverter is broken in some way, preventing the binding from working as intended. That's it. I guess you have your work laid out. I suggest you take a dive deep into your code with the help of the debugger and see whether your code is affected by one or multiple of the problem scenarios i mentioned here...

Comment: Just wanted to let the other users know that i´ve searched for answers, don´t know why u feel attacked by a ironic sentence. But thanks for ur answers anyway. 1 + 2 a new Model is generated thats y a wrote that true is reached later. 3 + 4 the binding and converter works thats y i wrote that its visibile when i change false to true. Maybe i didn´t explain the problem good enough.

Comment: I didn't feel attacked. No offence was taken. But i feel that such outright silly nonsense deserves a response of similar caliber. All is good ;-)

Comment: "_1 + 2 a new Model is generated_" If i understand you correctly here than this can be a possible problem as i mentioned in my point/scenario (2).

Comment: (Btw, just as a side note: It looks wrong if you create new instances of your viewmodel just because some state in your program changed. Try to avoid that and rethink your design choices for your program code...)

Comment: Found a way with **messaging** which changes the value before the ViewModel is (re-)loaded.